# How to find software jobs that require travel?

Tags: travel

Currently, I work as a C++ programmer in the financial services industry in Chicago (USA). I rarely see software job postings that explicitly state that it requires traveling which I actually would desire in a job. I have searched on sites like stackoverflow, Dice, Careerbuilder, and Indeed. A large majority of job postings for my skillset (primarily C++) and area (Chicago) are in the financial industry and none of them require travel. Should I be looking somewhere else to find these types of jobs? Are there certain types of companies or sectors that would contain software jobs requiring travel?

Comment: At NVIDIA devtech jobs are "60% or more traveling". Look for integration jobs, i.e. helping on-site customers integrating your systems into theirs.

Comment: Work contract jobs with large enough gaps in-between so you can travel at your leisure.

Comment: Join any of the Big 4. Or outfits that deploy in-house consultants like IBM. They'll make you sick of living out of a suitcase soon enough.

Comment: uh, ask a recruiter.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have no idea what you're actually looking for.

- Software jobs that do are probably going to involve 12 month plus contracts since you'll need to work onsite as part of a team. You could also just work at a software company in a city you've always wanted to live in for 12 months, for 12 months...
- There's plenty of jobs that let you work remotely. StackExchange is one. Just work there then go travel wherever.
- "Required traveling" is generally bad. You have to live in a hotel and eat hotel food and get very used to getting work done on airplanes. People with jobs that require travel usually try to find jobs that don't require travel as soon as they can. This makes me think you don't actually know what this means.
- Or maybe you just mean a company that occasionally sponsors vacations to places around the world? Most companies give you vacation days and a salary greater than the cost of living, which you can use to take vacations.
- Or maybe you mean a company with a team split across two locations so once you're a project manager you have to be in both places a lot? In that case, you'll be traveling a bit between two locations, and in my very limited experience, this can be pleasant. I can't really imagine how you would begin searching for that, though.

In conclusion: move somewhere you like or take vacations or work remotely. Isn't it weird to be asking for something to be required you want to do without being required?

Comment: +1 for `"Required traveling" is generally bad.` It gets old quickly.

Comment: +1. To the OP, be careful for what you wish for... when the company asks you to go somewhere, they will expect you to work rather than be a tourist (possibly more hours than normal to maximise your usefulness while there), it may well be somewhere you don't want to be (anywhere from boring to downright unpleasant), it will be on their timetable rather than holiday season, and unless you're pretty senior it will be on economy travel and budget hotels.

Answer (score 9):

Writing inhouse software for companies rarely involves travel. It just does not grant any benefit to the company. Working for a consulting company writing software for other client companies may involve more travel because working on-site in the place where the client company is located has it's advantages. So look for consulting companies. They may even be willing to hire you at a place they are not located, because who cares if you live in one place and they are in a second place when they send you to a third place to work anyway.

Comment: Absolutely.  I worked for a consulting company, and left because of the onerous travel requirements.  The only downside is that "travel" may mean being at the same job site for 6 months at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I have generally found it easy to determine if a job involves travel when looking at company websites.

I find that they include ranges of percentages.

- Zero means zero.
- Less than 10% means mostly zero but can't commit to zero.
- 10% means every few months.
- 25% means once a month.

The text description will give lengths of trips if they are longer than a week. Remember 25% is also 3 month long trips a year. Also pay attention to see if it involves international travel.

Look for companies that have contracts with the government.